# A question about friend functions

Tags: c++, friend

I faced a problem recently with a 3rd party library which generates classes from a xml. Here is a gist of it:

```
class B;
class A
{
    void doSomething();
    friend class B; 
};

class B
{
    void doSomething();
    void doSomethingMore()
    {
        doSomething();
    }
};
```

The compiler flags call to the function `doSomething()` as ambiguous and flags it as an compiler error. It is easy to understand why it gives the error.`Class B` being friend of `class A`, every member of `class B` has access to all the members of `class A`. Renaming of the either of functions resolved my problem but it got me thinking that shouldn't in this case the compiler should give a priority to the class's own member function over the function in another class of which it is a friend?

Note: I will update the compiler version details tomorrow..Need to check the exact version details at the workplace. I guess i should have got them in first place..:(

[Problem Update & Resolution]
I checked out again with a small sample program and my bad the problem is not with the ambiguity due to friend functions. The 3rd party library internally generates a function with the same signature and inside the same class which causes the ambiguity. Thanks for the replies, at least my misconception got corrected :)

Comment: What compiler are you using and how are you instantiating the objects?

Comment: For compiler issues, please give the compiler name (and version) as well as the exact error message. Some compilers are known to have shortcomings, some issue messages that can be misinterpreted :)

Comment: @Thomas: I will update the details tomorrow..Need to check the exact version details on the Unix Box at work place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no ambiguity. The function called in A requires an A instance. The function called in B requires a B instance.

doSomethingMore is called on a B instance and therefore the function that gets called is the one in B.

You seem to have misunderstood friendship. All it means is that, in this case, given an instance of A, member functions of B can call the A::doSomething() function or do anything else in A that has  private access.

Comment: Exactly my initial thinking, but unfortunately it flagged me an error.

Answer (score 0):

There's absolutely no ambiguity in your example. Making one class friend of another has no such effect on the name lookup as you describe. The "It is easy to understand..." explanation does not really make much sense from the language point of view.

While it is possible that a broken compiler might behave the way you describe, most likely you missed something and the reason for the ambiguity is different.

Comment: Just renaming one of the doSomething() function resolves my problem. I am wondering if it is a broken compiler..

Comment: @Als; Well, if the compiler says it is ambiguous, then it must be ambiguous to the compiler. And renaming should solve it, of course. I'm just saying that it is likely that the source of that ambiguity is not friendship (unless the compiler is broken).

Comment: I guess i will try compiling the minimalistic code sample above on the same compiler and then check the behavior, that should reveal more info..